# Beat count-to-time converter (task #2)

Tags: c++, interview-questions, converting, music

About a year ago, I was given a C++ assignment as a preliminary job-interview test.

The assignment included 4 different tasks, from which I had to choose one.

I actually chose and completed 3 out of 4 tasks, but I did not pass the test.

I was not given any specific rejections, so I would like to get an unbiased opinion.

---

[image]

---

### My answer:

**File main.cpp:**

```
// Assumptions:
// 1. At least one warp-marker is defined
// 2. The end-tempo is defined after the last warp-marker
// 3. The end-tempo is defined before the first conversion

#include "MarkerSet.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static void Run(istream& input);

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
        Run(ifstream(argv[1])); // read line by line from an input file
    else
        Run(cin); // read line by line from stdin (i.e., from the keyboard)
    return 0;
}

static void Run(istream& input)
{
    MarkerSet markerSet;
    while (!input.eof())
    {
        string keyword;
        input>>keyword;
        if (keyword.compare("marker") == 0)
        {
            double beatTime;
            double sampTime;
            input>>beatTime>>sampTime;
            markerSet.AddEntry(beatTime,sampTime);
        }
        else if (keyword.compare("end_tempo") == 0)
        {
            double endTempo;
            input>>endTempo;
            markerSet.SetEndTempo(endTempo);
        }
        else if (keyword.compare("b2s") == 0)
        {
            double beatTime;
            input>>beatTime;
            cout<<markerSet.B2S(beatTime)<<endl;
        }
        else if (keyword.compare("s2b") == 0)
        {
            double sampTime;
            input>>sampTime;
            cout<<markerSet.S2B(sampTime)<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**File MarkerSet.h:**

```
#ifndef MARKER_SET
#define MARKER_SET

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MarkerSet
{
public:
    MarkerSet();
    virtual ~MarkerSet();
public:
    void AddEntry(double beatTime,double sampTime);
    void SetEndTempo(double endTempo);
public:
    double B2S(double beatTime) const;
    double S2B(double sampTime) const;
protected:
    int numOfEntries;
    vector<double> beatTimes;
    vector<double> sampTimes;
    double endTempo;
};

#endif
```

**File MarkerSet.cpp:**

```
// Assumptions:
// 1. For every warp-markers 'i' and 'j', beatTimes[i] < beatTimes[j] IFF sampTimes[i] < sampTimes[j]
// 2. The puporse of this task is to provide a correct implementation rather than an efficient implementation
//    I should probably use <set> instead of <vector> in order to make functions 'B2S' and 'B2S' more efficient

#include "MarkerSet.h"
#include <algorithm>

MarkerSet::MarkerSet()
{
    numOfEntries = 1;
    beatTimes.push_back(0.0);
    sampTimes.push_back(0.0);
}

MarkerSet::~MarkerSet()
{
}

void MarkerSet::AddEntry(double beatTime,double sampTime)
{
    numOfEntries++;
    beatTimes.push_back(beatTime);
    sampTimes.push_back(sampTime);
    sort(beatTimes.begin(),beatTimes.end());
    sort(sampTimes.begin(),sampTimes.end());
}

void MarkerSet::SetEndTempo(double endTempo)
{
    this->endTempo = endTempo;
}

double MarkerSet::B2S(double beatTime) const
{
    for (int i=0; i<numOfEntries; i++)
    {
        if (beatTimes[i] > beatTime)
            return (beatTime-beatTimes[i-1])/(beatTimes[i]-beatTimes[i-1])*(sampTimes[i]-sampTimes[i-1])+sampTimes[i-1];
    }
    return (beatTime-beatTimes[numOfEntries-1])/endTempo+sampTimes[numOfEntries-1];
}

double MarkerSet::S2B(double sampTime) const
{
    for (int i=0; i<numOfEntries; i++)
    {
        if (sampTimes[i] > sampTime)
            return (sampTime-sampTimes[i-1])/(sampTimes[i]-sampTimes[i-1])*(beatTimes[i]-beatTimes[i-1])+beatTimes[i-1];
    }
    return (sampTime-sampTimes[numOfEntries-1])*endTempo+beatTimes[numOfEntries-1];
}
```

**Tested input:**

```
marker     1.0  5.0
marker     7.0  8.0
marker     9.0 12.0
marker    19.0 14.0
end_tempo 10.0
b2s       0.0
b2s       0.1
b2s       0.5
b2s       1.0
b2s       2.0
b2s       3.0
b2s       4.0
b2s       5.0
b2s       6.0
b2s       7.0
b2s       8.0
b2s       9.0
b2s       10.0
b2s       11.0
b2s       12.0
b2s       13.0
b2s       14.0
b2s       15.0
b2s       16.0
b2s       17.0
b2s       18.0
b2s       19.0
b2s       20.0
b2s       21.0
b2s       22.0
b2s       23.0
b2s       24.0
b2s       25.0
b2s       26.0
b2s       27.0
b2s       28.0
b2s       29.0
s2b        0.0
s2b        1.0
s2b        2.0
s2b        3.0
s2b        4.0
s2b        5.0
s2b        6.0
s2b        7.0
s2b        8.0
s2b        9.0
s2b       10.0
s2b       11.0
s2b       12.0
s2b       13.0
s2b       14.0
s2b       15.0
s2b       16.0
s2b       17.0
s2b       18.0
s2b       19.0
```

Comment: If this were a real problem and not just an assignment, I'd recommend checking for errors upon opening the input file `Run(ifstream(argv[1]));`, rather than just proceeding blindly.

Comment: @200_success: What is the rapidly changing event mentioned here.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I asked to delete this question along with two others, which had already been answered (and therefore I could not delete them myself). This question was deleted, but the other two weren't. So I decided I might as well have this one here too (they're all related). In any case, after I re-added this question (I had to ask for moderator's help on that if I remember correctly), it came along with that "rapidly changing event" note. I would be happy if it was removed somehow, though I have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 2):

### using namespace std

Don't use:

```
using namespace std;
```

See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

***Absolutely*** never use it in a header file:

```
#ifndef MARKER_SET
#define MARKER_SET

#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

By putting this in a header file. You are basically infecting the source of any code that uses your header file. You can introduce breaking changes into other peoples code just because they include your header file. This is enough to get you banned as an author from projects.

### Looping with !eof()

This is an anti-pattern (in all languages)

```
while (!input.eof())
```

You have to remember that the EOF flag is not set until you read past the eof. But the last successful read will read up-to (but not past) the eof. Thus the last succesful read will leave the stream with no data in it but the EOF flag is not set. So your while condition will let the loop be entered when there is no data to be read.

This can still work. But you must also check that the any subsequent read operation worked.

```
 while(!input.eof())
 {
    string keyword;
    if (input >> keyword)
    {
        // There was good input so we can continue
    }
 }
```

But the normal pattern (in all languages) is to test the result of the read operation.

```
 string keyword;
 while(input >> keyword)
 {
     // There was good input so we can continue
 }
```

As you can see your original method makes the code longer and uglier and harder to read over the standard way of reading from a stream.

There is also the hidden danger that the loop will never exit. If the stream `input` goes into a bad state then it will stop reading from the underlying stream and all operations will fail (until the state is reset to clean). If the stream is an a bad state (and thus refusing to read more data) it will never reach the eof and thus the EOF flag will never be set (thus an infinite loop).

The stream can go into a bad state if you try and read a value from the stream and it fails (in your case if you try and read a number and it finds a string (say because of bad input) then stream will have the `bad bit` set.

So you should test for `good()` not `eof()` unless you explicitly check for and correct bad state. Even this is error prone (forgetting to check in one branch may break your code again and lead to an infinite loop).

Looking at your input. I would change this so that you read line at a time. Then parse the line based in its own stream. That way the main stream `input` never goes bad as you are reading a line at a time. And any errors are checked when reading from the individual line streams.

```
 std::string line;
 while(std::getline(input, line))
 {
     // Read a line from the input and it worked.
     std::stringstream  linestream(line);

     std::string   keyword;
     if (linestream >> keyword)
     {
         // Not an empty line.
         if (keyword == "marker")
         {
             double beatTime;
             double sampTime;
             if (linestream >> beatTime >> sampTime)
             {
                 // Only perform operation if both reads worked correctly.
                 markerSet.AddEntry(beatTime,sampTime);


                 // Depending on how stringent you are you may
                 // also want to validate there is no more data
                 // left on the end of the line.
             }
         }
```

### Use == to test for equality

This:

```
    if (keyword.compare("marker") == 0)
```

is much easier to read as (as its meaning is implied):

```
    if (keyword == "marker")
```

### Prefer "\n" over std::endl

```
        cout<<markerSet.B2S(beatTime)<<endl;
```

The difference between `"\n"` and `std::endl` is that the latter forces a flush of the stream. This is rarely what you want. Streams are buffered so that they efficiently flush themselves when required. Flushing them over frequently results in sever performance problems. If you really wanted it to flush use an un-buffered stream (you should not be imposing this on the user of your code, let the user of your code decide if they want immediate feedback by choosing an un-buffered stream).

### Don't bother with protected

```
class MarkerSet
{
protected:
```

Protected does not buy you anything. It does not protect your code (if I want to bypass I just inherit from your class). Now encapsulation is broken. Even Stroustroup in several interviews has mentioned that it was a bad idea (Java's package level is what he was aiming for).

Make member variables private. If you must add Get/Set but I think those also break encapsulation (but that is a bit situational).

### Don't use `this->`

```
this->endTempo = endTempo;
```

This means you have done a bad job of naming your variables and you are compensating for shadowing (which the compiler will warn you about (and if you set the compiler settings correctly all warnings are errors (any tester will definately look at warnings as logical errors in your code; your code should always compile with zero warnings (if it does not then new warning that may be important will be lost in the flood of old warnings))). By using better names this becomes redundant.

### Always use {} on sub blocks

```
   if (beatTimes[i] > beatTime)
        return (beatTime-beatTimes[i-1])/(beatTimes[i]-beatTimes[i-1])*(sampTimes[i]-sampTimes[i-1])+sampTimes[i-1];
```

There are a few corner cases where this becomes an issue. Best to just get in the habit of using braces so you never fall into them.

### C++14 for syntax

If you have the new C++14 you can use the new for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<numOfEntries; i++)
{
    if (beatTimes[i] > beatTime)

// Can be written like this:
for(auto beat : beatTimes)
{
   if (beat > beatTime)
```

Also keeping a separate count outside the vector `numOfEntries` is risky (You are assuming that a maintainer of your code will correctly maintain this relationship). The vector knows how big it is you should use that. If you don't have C++14 you should be using iterators (with begin()/end()) to loop over vectors (or any other container).